# alternative to replacing my gas shut off valve

Tags: gas, shutoff

I am installing a new gas range and the home depot person that came to install told me that I would need to replace the gas shut off valve behind the range before they install. They need a standard 1/2" thread on the shut off valve while the shut off valve that i have is 1/2 inch on the gas line side but has a flare end on the other side.

Now, the plumber is quoting $250 to just install the shut off valve. And I do not want to do it myself since it is gas. However, I have started to think whether I can circumvent the whole problem by putting a connector like this: http://www.midlandhardware.com/207955.html . The male flare can go into the flare end of the shut off valve and the other end can be a standard 1/2" thread.

The question is whether this is an OK situation or is not accepted to do this on a gas line.

Comment: Go back to home depot and explain to the sales department what valve you have. He can sell you a flexible gas line that comes with flare fitting adapters. Discard those fittings you do not need, get a real installer not the one that came to fleece you of your hard earned cash, and have the gas range installed. Tell the first guy to shove his $250.00, you know where.

Answer (score 0):

That is an adaptor from standard pipe thread to flare. You still need a shutoff of some kind. Shutoffs are not much more expensive than adaptors. Probably less than $10 difference. Almost all of the $250 is for labor. He would likely charge you the same to just install the adapter. You need a shutoff valve for servicing and code requirements. Otherwise you would have to shut off the whole house if there were a leak or some other problem.

Comment: There is a shutoff valve behind the range since he was able to shut off the gas to the range when he thought initially that the install might work. I think the problem is that the shut off valve does not have a standard 1/2" end but a flare end. And they want to use their own flare end that goes into the 1/2" thread on the shut off valve.